# Create SQL Database From DBContext EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My pc suddenly got sick and all the data are removed and no way to recover them.

I was working on several projects with .NET 5 using EF core 6 Database first approach.

I cloned my projects from GitHub to get them back but unfortunately I don't have a backup or SQL file for the database.

Is there any way to create the database from the dbContext in the .NET 5 project?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way was running these commands:

Add-Migration InitialCreate

and Then:

Update-Database

Answer (score 3):

I do not quite understand the question, is perhaps meant something like this?

```
//creates an instance of the class where the "database" is
Database db = new Database();

//creates the database if it does not exist
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Comment: @gsharp It doesn't matter, anyway thanks that I can write comments now (have 59 points) To be honest, I hate this system. 
I also delete my comments and we act as if it never happened :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();`

With this your DataBase structure will be re-created from the model. Of course, there will be no data, just empty tables, indexes etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can re-create the database structure with your existing model.
But there is no way to recover the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in startup.cs file or program.cs '.net core 6'

```
`dbContext.Database.Migrate()`
```

This line will update database with all migrations which not applied on database